Create xarray Dataset with summary stats for each variable
I have an xarray with time, latitude, longitude and a number of variables (temperature, humidity etc.).
I would like to create a summary xarray dataset such that I can the stats as follow:
dfStats.sel(stat='mean').temperature

The behavior I'm looking for is the same as when you calculate quantiles:
dfQuants = df.quantile(dim=['lat','lon'], q=[.025,.25,.5,.75,.975])
dfQuants.sel(quantile=.025).temperature

Is this possible?
For reference, in pandas I would do it like this:
df.to_dataframe().drop(columns=['lat','lon']).groupby(['time']).agg(['mean', 'std'])

Edit:
I found a way to do it, but it's quite convoluted compared to pandas:
dfVar = df.var(dim=['lat','lon'])
dfStd = df.std(dim=['lat','lon'])
dfMean = df.mean(dim=['lat','lon'])

dfStats = dfVar.assign_coords(stat='var').expand_dims(dim='stat').merge(
    dfStd.assign_coords(stat='std').expand_dims(dim='stat').merge(
    dfMean.assign_coords(stat='mean').expand_dims(dim='stat')))

Hoping there is a better way!
